# Замена пустых значений по условию

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть DataFrame об опросе уровня счастья в разных странах.

```
                     Country  happiness_score  gdp_per_capita    family    health   freedom  generosity  government_trust  dystopia_residual      continent  Year  social_support  cpi_score
0                    Norway           7.5370        1.616463  1.533524  0.796667  0.635423    0.362012          0.315964           2.277027         Europe  2015        0.000000         88
1                   Denmark           7.5220        1.482383  1.551122  0.792566  0.626007    0.355280          0.400770           2.313707         Europe  2015        0.000000         91
2                   Iceland           7.5040        1.480633  1.610574  0.833552  0.627163    0.475540          0.153527           2.322715         Europe  2015        0.000000         79
3               Switzerland           7.4940        1.564980  1.516912  0.858131  0.620071    0.290549          0.367007           2.276716         Europe  2015        0.000000         86
4                   Finland              NaN        1.443572  1.540247  0.809158  0.797000    0.245483          0.382612           2.430182         Europe  2015        0.000000         90
5               Netherlands           7.3770        1.503945  1.428939  0.810696  0.585384    0.470490          0.282662           2.294804         Europe  2015        0.000000         84
6                    Canada           7.3160        1.479204  1.481349  0.834558  0.611101    0.435540          0.287372           2.187264  North America  2015        0.000000         83
7               New Zealand           7.3140        1.405706  1.548195  0.816760  0.614062    0.500005          0.382817           2.046456      Australia  2015        0.000000         91
8                    Sweden           7.2840        1.494387  1.478162  0.830875  0.612924    0.385399          0.384399           2.097538         Europe  2015        0.000000         89
9                 Australia           7.2840        1.484415  1.510042  0.843887  0.601607    0.477699          0.301184           2.065211      Australia  2015        0.000000         79
10                   Israel           7.2130        1.375382  1.376290  0.838404  0.405989    0.330083          0.085242           2.801757           Asia  2015        0.000000         61
```

[DataFrame](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ajDXBgQKty9SawTgsb1jJPQt-LcKllMP/view?usp=sharing)

Задача состоит в том, чтобы заполнить Nan данные по happiness_score средним значением из уже имеющихся данных для каждой страны. Удалось найти среднее значение по каждой стране, но зашел в тупик.

```
for_country_avg_1 = df.groupby('Country')['happiness_score'].sum()
for_country_avg_2 = df.groupby('Country').size()
country_avg = for_country_avg_1 / for_country_avg_2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, решение использовать группировку - верное, осталось лишь доработать код. Во-первых, в pandas есть встроенная функция вычисления среднего (`mean`), во-вторых, есть отличный метод `transform`, который можно использовать для заполнения nan-значений с помощью аксессора `fillna`:

```
df["happiness_score"] = df.groupby("Country")["happiness_score"].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
```

df:

```
         Country  happiness_score  gdp_per_capita    family    health   freedom  generosity  government_trust  dystopia_residual continent  Year  social_support  cpi_score
0         Norway          7.53700        1.616463  1.533524  0.796667  0.635423    0.362012          0.315964           2.277027    Europe  2015        0.000000         88
1        Denmark          7.52200        1.482383  1.551122  0.792566  0.626007    0.355280          0.400770           2.313707    Europe  2015        0.000000         91
2        Iceland          7.50400        1.480633  1.610574  0.833552  0.627163    0.475540          0.153527           2.322715    Europe  2015        0.000000         79
3    Switzerland          7.49400        1.564980  1.516912  0.858131  0.620071    0.290549          0.367007           2.276716    Europe  2015        0.000000         86
4        Finland          7.60574        1.443572  1.540247  0.809158  0.797000    0.245483          0.382612           2.430182    Europe  2015        0.000000         90
. . .
```

проверяем на примере Финляндии на исходной таблице:

```
df.loc[df["Country"]=="Finland","happiness_score"].mean()
```

> 7.6057400170000005